# Хочу спарсить данные с сайта которые появляются после заполнения поля с адресом

Tags: python, парсер

Мне необходимо скачать данные о графике отключения горячей воды в г. Москва с сайта [МОЭК](https://www.moek.ru/hotwater/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл библиотеку beautifulsoup4 на python но как делать запрос с POST и GET не разобрался. 
Поскольку сайт выдаёт информацию по графику отключения после ввода улицы и номера дома писать костыль с перебором всех улиц глупо решил спросить совета у опытных программистов здесь. Может у кого была подобная задача, подскажите в какую сторону копать чтобы её решить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае парсер необязателен и не требуется в целом. Данные приходят get-запросом. Поэтому можно их отправлять самостоятельно. К примеру, следующим образом.

```
import locale
from requests import get
from datetime import datetime

address = 'Арбатецкая ул., д.2, стр.3'
url = f'https://hotwater.moek.ru/api/works?addr={address}'
data = get(url).json()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru') # windows
format = '%d %B %Y %X'
start = datetime.fromisoformat(data['beg']).strftime(format)
end = datetime.fromisoformat(data['end']).strftime(format)
print('Начало', start, 'окончание', end)
# Начало 14 Июль 2020 14:00:01 окончание 24 Июль 2020 13:59:01
```